# Ajuda Portugol(ordem crescente)

Tags: portugol

O código abaixo deveria ordenar os números digitados em ordem crescente, porém, quando é digitado 5,3 e 8 respectivamente, o programa os apresenta fora de ordem.

programa
{

```
funcao inicio()
{
    //variaveis
    inteiro i
    real a, b, c
    real menor=0.0, meio=0.0, maior=0.0

    leia(i)
    leia(a)
    leia(b)
    leia(c)

    se(i==1){
        se(a>b e b>c)
        maior = a
        meio = b
        menor = c
    }


         senao se(a>c e c>b){
         maior = a
         meio = c
         menor = b
    }


        senao se(b>a e a>c){
         maior = b
         meio = a
         menor = c
         }


        senao se(b>c e c>a){
         maior = b
         meio = c
         menor = a
         }


          senao se(c>a e a>b){
         maior = c
         meio = a
         menor = b
         }

     senao se(c>b e b>a){
         maior = c
         meio = b
         menor = a
         }

       escreva("\nmenor = ", menor)
       escreva("\nmeio = ", meio)
       escreva("\nmaior = ", maior) 

}
```

}

Comment: pq existe a variavel `i` e quando devemos entrar no `se i==1`?

Comment: O problema proposto pelo professor tem diversas condições, como por exemplo, i==2, i==3, mas a minha dificuldade é só na ordem crescente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você cometeu um pequeno erro de atenção. Veja este trecho do seu código:

```
se(i==1){
        se(a>b e b>c) //Falta a chave de abertura aqui
        maior = a
        meio = b
        menor = c
    }
```

Você abriu as chaves do condicional `se(i==1){` corretamente, entretanto você não abriu as chaves da próxima estrutura condicional, e como variável `b` ( valendo 3) não é maior que a variável `c` ( valendo 8) você nunca entrava nesta condicional, saindo erroneamente do código!

Para corrigir insira uma chave de abertura logo após o `se(a>b e b>c)` .

Seu código ficará assim:

```
    se(i==1){
            se(a>b e b>c){ //Codigo corrigido
            maior = a
            meio = b
            menor = c
        }
...
```

Comment: entendi, caso eu queira adicionar uma outra condicional, por exemplo, se(i==2) para ordem decrescente, sigo o mesmo modelo?

Comment: só inverta os sinais, mas vou fazer uma simulação aqui, a resposta te ajudou?

Comment: bastante, pensei nessa possibilidade de só inverter os sinais mesmo, mas não estou tendo nenhum retorno, o programa termina.

Comment: @JoãoRosa consegui aqui:( farei no primeiro se para exemplo) o seu código atual está assim: `se(a>b e b>c){` coloque assim: `se(b>a e c>b)` observe que não mudei o operador `>` e sim troquei os operandos!`a>b` virou `b>a` faça isto em todo seu código! e apos isto mude a variável  `menor` para `maior` sem trocar atribuição! ou seja: `maior = a meio = c menor = b` ficará: `menor = a meio = c maior = b`